# How to do an android mm clean?

Tags: android, makefile, android-build

I'm building custom module in Android source using the `mm` command.

When I run `mm clean`, it seems that the whole project is cleaned.

How can I restrict the clean to just the current module?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `mm -B`, it will rebuild all, equivalent to clean and then make.

Comment: Is there a way to only clean the module (not rebuild)?  I'd like to be able to test that my app can build with mm/mmm and then clean it such that it needs to be built afresh during the full ROM build.

Comment: -B, --always-make     Unconditionally make all targets // seems whole project was rebuild, oh my god

Comment: tips: must run in module folder, otherwise whole project will rebuild

Comment: I tried doing `mm -B` but got `Unknown option: -B` -- has mm changed somehow on AOSP 8.1?

Comment: mm -help gives me "Unknown option -help" Same with --help

Comment: I use `mm clean ` and work

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do without mm is to give `make clean-<target name>` from root of Android source.

Similarly you can build the required module alone with `make <target name>`

Comment: Note for interested readers: That's not quite the same thing.  `make` from the root will trace through ALL build files (*.mk) in the entire tree.  `mm` from a subdirectory will only trace through the build files in that directory.  This is an important distinction because tracing through all the make files is time consuming and sometimes error prone.

Comment: Some build dependencies are not identified when using `mm` from a folder. Often I have found people submitting patches based on their build passing through `mm` but would fail at root level.

Answer (score 6):

On older make-based AOSP build system, use

```
mm -B
```

to rebuild the module.

On newer Ninja+Soong based AOSP build systems, it seems that `-B` no longer works. It gives the error `Unknown option: -B`.

One possible alternative is to use the `NINJA_ARGS` environment variable to pass additional Ninja arguments to underlying build engine.

For example, the following command removes all output and intermediate files:

```
NINJA_ARGS="-t clean" mm
```

In this case **clean** is an extra tool to the Ninja build system. See https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools for other tools.

One thing to notice is that the **clean** tool seems to clear all the dependencies of the module, instead of the module itself. I haven't found a way to assign a rule to limit the clean scope to the module only.

references: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/best_practices.md

Comment: The NINJA_ARGS method is not a good option for later version of ASOP. It will clean out **everything**, not just your module.  The system will the need to rebuild many ASOP tools and components which will take forever.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing "clean-" to the module name will do the clean build in Android

For ex,
m clean-libskia

Answer (score 0):

`make <lib> 2>&1 | grep -e "install"`

This will make the  and print all the libs that were re-compiled.