# Android Oreo new build system (soong / ninja)

Tags: android, android-ndk, ninja, android-soong

I am in the process of migrating an NDK application from AOSP 7 to 8 and right away I have two (related) issues.

1) I used to build my module with `mm -B`, but now it seems `-B` is no longer an accepted option.

2) How can I do a clean of just my module? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074431/how-to-do-an-android-mm-clean) was pre AOSP 8 and instructed doing an `mm -B` which is no longer an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't. Soong tracks dependencies properly (unlike our old make system) so you don't ever need to do the equivalent of `mm -B`. If you find any cases to the contrary that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Google has people in charge of Android that are, literally, learning as they go, like Dan Albert. So I would expect answers of the type "You cannot do this...because we say so". No reasoning behind it. It is one of the worst build environments to work with on the planet. In your case, I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).