# How to clean a module in AOSP?

Tags: android, makefile, android-build

This is the same question as  [previously another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074431/how-to-do-an-android-mm-clean) which I found the solution in is invalid.
Because the command `mm -B` is invalid.

So how could I clean one specific module in AOSP with clean the other part?

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

how to make clean module in android

```
 $ make clean-<moudlename>
```

eg: make clean-libxyz (to clean libxyz.so)

https://dolinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-make-clean-module-in-android.html

or

NINJA_ARGS="-t clean" mm

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that , we can build a simple module with this command:

```
mmm “path to build”
```

but we cannot clean a module with this command. to perform cleaning source , you should use this command:

```
make clean
```